# How can I open a file without an extension or known file type?

Tags: image, macos, file

I was given a 700Mb CD from my boss from 2002. The files are either videos or pictures, she can't remember. I loaded the CD onto my mac to find that the files do not have extensions. I have tried adding several different extensions to the files (.mp4, .flv, .jpg, .png, .bmp, etc.) but my mac still cannot open them. I've tried loading them into VLC, and while VLC can recognize that the files have different durations (meaning they are probably videos), it still cannot play the videos. When I open the files in TextEdit, the first line looks like this:

```
    ˇˇimprDè¸PICTéÆdOˇ÷Original Image6<˜ÊµéÆpˇˇˇˇˇp
```

I've also tried the GetFileInfo command in Terminal on one of the files, and get the following output:

```
    file: "/Users/Me/Desktop/CD 1/myfile"
    type: "\0\0\0\0"
    creator: "\0\0\0\0"
    attributes: avbstclinmedz
    created: 06/07/2017 21:42:04
    modified: 06/07/2017 21:42:04
```

Any other suggestions? I'd really like to find out what on this disc! Thanks.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/file` say anything useful about them?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the few bytes of header, one might suspect it's a PICT format.  Please see [PICT format](https://www.google.com/search?q=pict%20file%20format%20specification&oq=pict%20file&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.6772j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  It's an old Mac format and since you mentioned you're using a Mac, perhaps that's what was used in your workplace 15 years ago, as well? See also [PICT format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/macpict/egff.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately adding .PCT as the extension did not fix  the problem. I don't think it's a picture, but most likely a video.

Comment: "PICT", plus the words "Original Image", led me to this section of code, which seems to support this theory: https://github.com/visad/visad/blob/master/deps/src/loci/formats/in/OpenlabReader.java#L408-L431

Comment: Very unlikely a video.  VLC reported them as "different durations" because the  PICT images are of different **sizes**.  Just google around for a tool that will open picts on your current Mac OS and then you'll know for sure.   If you accept the answer then so will I. ;)

Comment: I've tried to open the file with Preview, GIMP, and Quicktime7 (some online sources said this could open PCT files). Could it be that I haven't added the extension properly? I changed the name of the file  to include .pct, in which I'm then prompted to confirm that I want to include this as the extension.

Comment: @Izzy You may want to try some of the other extension variants mentioned in the Wikipedia article and other sources.   You may need to use a byte or hex editor to see the actual bytes in the header and compare them with the details located at [link](http://www.fileformat.info/format/macpict/egff.htm) to make sure they're really PICTs.

Answer (score 0):

imagine the file name is `myfile` with no extension like `myfile.txt` so click on the magnifier icon
[image]
and type `Terminal`. In the terminal change your directory to where your file is located using the `cd` command. I have created a file using the `touch` command in the Terminal (with no content), added a line into it and then showed its stuff on the terminal using cat command (or if the content is more than one page suggest to use less command). Or if you want to edit it you could use `vim` command for example.

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ touch myfile
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ echo "hello" >> myfile
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ cat myfile
hello
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ less myfile
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ 
Monas-MacBook-Pro:test mona$ vi myfile
```

Another option is installing `Notepad++` and rightclicking on the file and choosing to open it with `Notepad++`.

If your file is an executable, you will see weird contents either by `vim` or `Notepad++`.
You can download Notepad++ from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: When I use vi, this is the first line: ^@^@ÿÿimpr^@^@^@^B^@5^@?^@^@^@^T^@D^@^@^@^@<8f>üPICT^@^@<8e>®^A^@^@^@^@^A^@^A^@^

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try FileJuicer to open these enigmatic files,  and it worked! I turns out that each file contained a series of pictures.